# Snapping end lines ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, line, snapping, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to snap 2 polylines features as the picture below :[image]

I would like to snap both end lines using tolerance distance ans only snap the nearest feature: from the red feature, choose the nearest line to the yellow one and snap it (extend it to the yellow end point).

I tried to use classic snapping and "new" snapping environment from ArcGIS editing session, but it works manually, and I would like to make this process for thousands of features...
That is why I also tried Snap Tool into Editing ToolBox, but this tool does not consider end points of the source feature, but feature vertices!

Does anyone has an answer which could save me from this problem please?

Comment: Feature to point (line-ends) and then snap to those points?

Comment: I tried this but once I created end points, this is the same problem: for the snap tool (into editing toolbox), my input is the polyline feature (the snap environment is the point feature) and it snaps from all vertices and not end points...

Comment: If my input is the feature point, it will move (snap) the feature point and not the polyline

Comment: Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Derive end points of red
- Derive end points of yellow
- Nearest yellow point for each red point, with nearX,nearY
- XY points from nearXY.
- Merge with red ends
- Points to line using red I'd
- Merge with red and dissolve on red I'd.
- Should work if directions are towards each other

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your reply but those days I had to change my work, so I did not have a look on this problem again since last time... Thanks for your help!